# How to respond to a friend suggestion

Tags: questions

One of my colleague has sent me a message.

> Hi xyz, this is my friend abc and you might become friends... Her parents are from qwe place

How should I respond to this message in a way saying that I am interested in meeting the person.

Comment: Ask your friend to give each of you the other's phone number.

Comment: What is wrong with "I am interested in meeting the person"?